# Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) App Crash on Android Device

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd, python-for-android

whenever I open my kivy app it freezes on a black screen and then crashes... has anyone experienced this issue?

**LOGS**

```
2023-04-17 19:45:10.737 21265-21307 libc                    org.test.myapp                       A  Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x40 in tid 21307 (SDLThread), pid 21265 (SDLActivity)
2023-04-17 19:45:10.927 21318-21318 DEBUG                   pid-21318                            A  pid: 21265, tid: 21307, name: SDLThread  >>> org.test.myapp <<<
2023-04-17 19:45:11.068 21318-21318 DEBUG                   pid-21318                            A        #04 pc 0000000000009b88  /data/data/org.test.myapp/files/app/_python_bundle/site-packages/kivy/graphics/vbo.so
2023-04-17 19:45:11.981  1768-21325 ActivityTaskManager     system_server                        W    Force finishing activity org.test.myapp/org.kivy.android.PythonActivity
2023-04-17 19:45:11.983  2739-7412  LauncherFsGestureCompat com.miui.home                        D  componentName is org.test.myapp/org.kivy.android.PythonActivity
2023-04-17 19:45:12.002 21265-21265 PythonActivity          org.test.myapp                       V  onPause()
2023-04-17 19:45:12.002 21265-21265 SDL                     org.test.myapp                       V  onPause()
2023-04-17 19:45:12.015  4741-6664  ProcessMonitor          com.miui.securitycenter.remote       I  onForegroundInfoChanged: ForegroundInfo{mForegroundPackageName='com.miui.home', mForegroundUid=10050, mForegroundPid=2739, mLastForegroundPackageName='org.test.myapp', mLastForegroundUid=10349, mLastForegroundPid=21265, mMultiWindowForegroundPackageName='null', mMultiWindowForegroundUid=-1, mFlags=0}
2023-04-17 19:45:12.017 10934-10971 GST                     com.xiaomi.joyose                    I  forePkg: com.miui.home, preForePkg: org.test.myapp
2023-04-17 19:45:12.023 21265-21265 SDL                     org.test.myapp                       V  onWindowFocusChanged(): false
2023-04-17 19:45:12.023 21265-21265 SDL                     org.test.myapp                       V  nativeFocusChanged()
2023-04-17 19:45:12.024  4741-6664  GameBoosterService      com.miui.securitycenter.remote       I  onForegroundInfoChanged: Cur=com.miui.home   last=org.test.myapp
2023-04-17 19:45:12.025  4741-6664  GameBoosterService      com.miui.securitycenter.remote       D  onGameStatusChange foreground:ForegroundInfo{mForegroundPackageName='com.miui.home', mForegroundUid=10050, mForegroundPid=2739, mLastForegroundPackageName='org.test.myapp', mLastForegroundUid=10349, mLastForegroundPid=21265, mMultiWindowForegroundPackageName='null', mMultiWindowForegroundUid=-1, mFlags=0}
2023-04-17 19:45:12.192  1768-5827  ActivityManager         system_server                        I  Process org.test.myapp (pid 21265) has died: cch CRE 
2023-04-17 19:45:12.195  1768-5827  ProcessManager          system_server                        D  skip restart org.test.myapp because this device is a lowmemory device!
```

**SPEC Changes**

```
source.include_exts = py,png,jpg,kv,atlas,db,txt

requirements = python3, kivy==2.1.0, kivymd, sql, pillow
```

Unexpected Application Crash on Android.

Answer (score 0):

Had same issue on my Samsung Android device and I found a way to build a stable `APK` with `kivymd` dependency see detail here:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/76644946/704681